# border-bottom: Animate via Javascript | Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the issue - modified the origin Pen http://codepen.io/bphillips201/pen/xGcEI to receive a responsive option for triangles on all screens and add a responsive link option to the years timeline when we stretch screen. Now I have it here http://codepen.io/Norozzz/pen/qqJxPE. But unsolved issue is:
**need to add animation to all of triangles to grow up**, as you can see, now it have only this one via Java - `<div class="data-item" id="item6">` it still from the source code BUT it doesn't responsive. I tried several ways with `id="#item5"` but without glory).. I will be grateful for your advice.
UPD. Also interesting to start the animation exact when a user scroll down to place with it.

Comment: Can't you use the class selector? $(".data-item")

Comment: Sorry, don't catch you..

Comment: All modified is now responsive but without animation as from source

Comment: See the Js tab of the original and compare with your codepen. You only have two animations coded in your current Js. The missing ones are similar.

Comment: Yeeah I saw a difference;) thats why I deleted an usable. Leave one as on source and one for modification

Comment: Guys, any more adeas? Nothing to solve the issue don't receive yet unfortunately ..